# Laravel 5 How to check password reset token if it has expired or not

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm developing a web app using Laravel 5, I used Laravel's `make:auth` scaffolding. I was able to send a password reset link with a token, which works well on my end. I have this kind of url after clicking on the reset link: *`http://example.com/password/reset/{reset_token}`*.
 Now, on my `auth.reset` blade file, I want to check first if the `{reset_token}` has already expired because it seems in the 60 minutes expiration time at **`config.auth.php`**, it doesn't seem to automatically remove expired tokens. So, I'm trying to make a manual function to check if reset token is still valid with this:

```
function validateReminderToken($token)
{
    // I want to add some filter here like
    // if (tokenExpired($token)) return false;     
    $res = DB::table('password_resets')->where('token', $token)->get();
    if (empty($res)  || $res === null) {
        return false;
    }

    $res = $res[0];
    return $res->email;
}
```

How can I do it? Is there some built-in way of checking if the token has expired? Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the `created_at` to check if a certain duration has passed from the time of insertion. For example you can do like so :

```
$token = DB::table('password_resets')
    ->where('token','=',$token)
    ->where('created_at','>',Carbon::now()->subHours(2))
    ->first();
```

Then check if the token exists.

Comment: Thank you so much @Mithredate. This really makes sense.

Comment: This doesn't work anymore in 5.4 since the token is now hashed in the DB.

Comment: In Laravel 5.4 tokens are now hashed. There is undocumented interface TokenRepositoryInterface which has method called exists(). Class tha timpolements that interface has that method for token validation.

Comment: @user777 Correct. Btw, do you know which concrete class has the exists() implementation?

Comment: Just found it. It resolves to `DatabaseTokenRepository`. That's where the token validation is done using the `exists` method.

Comment: @crabbly I did it like this: $reminder = Reminder::where('email', $user->email)->first();
if (! $reminder or ! Hash::check($resetToken, $reminder->token)) {
    return $this->respondNotFound();
} where Reminder is user_reminders ( by default in laravel: password_resets

Comment: @user991 thanks for the update about 5.4, I think you should put that on as another answer

Answer (score 9):

To verify if the reset token has expired, simply check the Laravel function `tokenExpired ($created_at, $token)`

This function only executes the following:

`return Carbon::parse($createdAt)->addSeconds($this->expires)->isPast();`

e.g.

```php
$created_at = DB::table('password_resets')->first()['created_at'];
// => 2018-01-08 09:59:26

// Carbon::now();
// => 2018-01-08 11:03:05

Carbon::parse($created_at)->addSeconds(config('auth.passwords.users.expire'*60))->isPast()
// => true (with an expiration setting of 1 hour)
```

Comment: Where can I find that `tokenExpired` function? on what class?

Comment: That function is in vendor folder, you can find it in the class `DatabaseTokenRepository` in `namespace Illuminate\Auth\Passwords;`

Comment: Cool, your answer seems far more relevant, than my accepted answer 3 years ago. Thanks for that!

Answer (score 5):

On >= Laravel 5.4

```
$reminder = Reminder::where('email', $user->email)->first();

if (! $reminder or ! Hash::check($resetToken, $reminder->token)) {
    // Return 404, as Reminder was not found
    return $this->respondNotFound();
}
```

Where `Reminder` is `password_resets` Eloquent Model ( by default in laravel: `password_resets` )

Answer (score -1):

Alternative way - is to call artisan command `auth:clear-resets`

Comment: This does not answer the question at all. OP asked how to check whether a given token has expired. The command you mentioned deletes expired tokens from the database.